# Javascript total return NaN for 4 digits num

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

Here is the javascript for calculating the price of the item the problem is that 
whenever the price is 4 digits the value that return is NaN.

here's my hidden field for the price:

```
<input type="hidden" name="price" id="price"class="price" value="4500"readonly >
```

here's for my quantity field

```
<input type="number" name="quant" id="quant" value="2" />
```

here's for my shipment fee

```
<select  id="shipment" onchange="myFunction3()" name="shipment2" disabled>

<option value="100" data-quantity="1">1 for 100 pesos </option>
</select
```

here's for the total price

```
<input type="text" id="demo" name="total_price" style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:5px;" readonly>
```

Script for changing the value of shipment

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('quant').addEventListener("keyup", function(){

  var value = parseInt(this.value, 20),
      selectEle = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0],
      options = selectEle.options,
      selectedNum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    //checking the exact string with spaces (" " + value + " ")
    if(options[i].textContent.indexOf(" " + value + " ") > -1) {
        selectedNum = i;
    }
 }
 selectEle.selectedIndex = selectedNum ? selectedNum : 0;   

 }, false);

 </script>
```

Calculating all the values

```
function myFunction3() {
var y= document.getElementById("shipment").value;
return y;
}

<script>
    $("#price,#quant,#shipment").keyup(function () {
      if(+myFunction3() =="" )
      {
        $('#demo').val(0);
      }
      else if($('#trigger')=="checked") //this is the problem
      {
        $('#demo').val($('#price').val() * $('#quant').val() ;
      }
      else
      {
      $('#demo').val($('#price').val() * $('#quant').val() + +myFunction3());
     }
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: `the value that return` - the value that is returned where? note: this is a real confusion of jquery and plain javascript - why such a mashup? always use jQuery style code, or never use it, makes little sense with the code you've posted to have such a mix of the two (in my opinion)

Comment: All works to me - https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/yop9ondz/

Comment: If you are going to use Jquery, please use the `.on('input')` event method. It is much more robust then the `keyup` binding.

Comment: `if(+myFunction3() == "")` is extremely weird… it converts an empty string to `0`, then compares to an empty string and thereby yields `true`. Why not remove that `+` or compare against `0` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this was just typed incorrectly in here, but you have a syntax error (missing closing parenthesis) near the problem area:

```
$('#demo').val($('#price').val() * $('#quant').val() ;
```

Should be:

```
$('#demo').val($('#price').val() * $('#quant').val());
```

I think it would be much better to ensure you aren't working with strings before you do math on them:

```
var price = parseInt($('#price').val(), 10);
var quantity = parseInt($('#quant').val(), 10);

$('#demo').val(price * quantity);
```

You could go further and ensure that neither of them are `NaN` prior to working with them:

```
var price = parseInt($('#price').val(), 10);
var quantity = parseInt($('#quant').val(), 10);

if(!isNaN(price) && !isNaN(quantity)) {
  $('#demo').val(price * quantity);
} else {
  alert('Please enter numbers only!');
}
```